# PHP code has replaced with '0000 0000 0000 0000....'

Tags: php

I am building a PHP project using MVC structure and I use SublimeText.

The project worked fine till yesterday but when I open the project folder today, **all the codes** of php files which are in the

```
controllers
```

folder and

```
libs
```

folder, has replaced with **zeros** with the pattern

```
**0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000**
```

This pattern continues in to number of lines.

Please, can anyone tell me why this happens? and How can I recover my code back?

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: Normal files shows their encoding as UTF-8 but, changed files shows 'Hexadecimal'. The solution you gave me did not work.

Comment: Try changing it to UTF-8 again

Comment: I tried saving file again with utf-8 encoding, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to delete zero width spaces in `Sublime Text` is using the search and replace functionality:

- Press Ctrl + h ( Alt + Cmd + f for Mac )
- Enable the Regular expression flag by clicking the leftmost button on the search panel or pressing Alt + r ( Alt + Cmd + r for Mac )
- Enter \x{200b} as the search term
- Make sure the "Replace with" field is empty and hit "Replace All"
- Plugins for solving this problem for good!

I searched for a plugin that would highlight all the possibly code breaking characters but couldn't find one for Sublime Text so I wrote one: https://github.com/TuureKaunisto/highlight-dodgy-chars

The plugin works on a whitelist principle: all non-ascii characters that are not whitelisted in the settings get highlighted.

If you want to highlight things based on your own regular expression, this plugin will do the trick: https://github.com/bluegray/Highlighter and is also easily installable via Package Manager.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the question, the problem seems to be that the code has been replaced and not about how to find hidden spaces?